# How to update JS variable in value field of charts.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, chart.js

On page load, a charts.js Chart is drawn (more on that below). I also have some checkboxes like...

```
            <input type="checkbox" id="something"  name="something" value="25" data-val="25" checked="checked" class="option">
            <label for="something">Something</label>

            <input type="checkbox" id="other"  name="other" value="5" data-val="5" checked="checked" class="option">
            <label for="other">Other</label>
```

I have this JS for creating variables and then seeing if a checkbox is checked or unchecked and then either keeping the value the same or giving it a new value of 0.  I also have an updateBreakdown() function which destroys the chart and re-draws it.

Below that is my code for a charts.js Chart.  Notice the data uses my variables for the "values".  On page load, the chart creates fine.  When I uncheck a box, for example, the "something" box, the value of the something variable should change to 0 and therefore, it should not take up ANY space on the chart when it gets re-drawn.  But it appears with 25 always.

So I could be wrong, but I feel like something is wrong with how I originally declare the variables and/or how I keep their scope?

Or maybe I just have to do something different to make the charts.js data "refresh" the variables that are being used as values?

Anyone see where I'm going wrong?

```
  <script>
    var something=25;
    var other=5;


    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $('.option').on('change', function() {

          if ($('#something').is(':checked')) {
              var something = 25;
          } else {
              var something = 0;
          }

           if ($('#other').is(':checked')) {
              var other= 5;
          } else {
              var other= 0;
          }

        updateBreakdown();

        });

    });

    function updateBreakdown() {

                // create the graph from scratch
                doughnutChart.destroy()
                doughnutChart = new Chart(ctx).Doughnut(doughnutData, {
                    percentageInnerCutout: 55
                });

            }

</script>
 <canvas id="breakdown" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
              <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/1.0.2/Chart.min.js"></script>
              <script>

                var ctx = document.getElementById("breakdown").getContext("2d");
                var doughnutData = [
                   {
                      value: something,
                      label: 'My something Label',
                      color: '#811BD6'
                   },
                   {
                      value: other,
                      label: 'My other label',
                      color: '#D18177'
                   }
                ];

                var doughnutChart = new Chart(ctx).Doughnut(doughnutData, {
                    percentageInnerCutout: 55
                });
</script>
```

Comment: Have you accidentally left out the closing script tag in your final script or is that just a typo?

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo

Comment: Don't you need to give `doughnutData` its new configuration data before you create the new chart after destroying the old one?

Comment: Yeah, I guess that's where I'm confused.  I incorrectly assumed when it re-drew the chart, it would used the most "up-to-date" values of the variables in the label fields, but evidently it doesn't work that way.  Is there a way to essentially have the Chart's values variables "refresh" with each checking/unchecking of the box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try giving doughnutData its new configuration data before you create the new chart.

```
function updateBreakdown() {

            // create the graph from scratch
            doughnutChart.destroy();
            var doughnutData = [
               {
                  value: something,
                  label: 'My something Label',
                  color: '#811BD6'
               },
               {
                  value: other,
                  label: 'My other label',
                  color: '#D18177'
               }
            ];
            doughnutChart = new Chart(ctx).Doughnut(doughnutData, {
                percentageInnerCutout: 55
            });

 }
```

And make this changes:

```
if ($('#something').is(':checked')) {
          //var something = 25;//replace these
            something = 25;//with these
      } else {
          //var something = 0;
            something = 0;
      }

       if ($('#other').is(':checked')) {
          //var other= 5;
            other= 5;
      } else {
          //var other= 0;
            other= 0;
      }
```

Comment: Just tried that, no luck.  Still keeping the original variable values regardless.  Thanks for the suggestion though!

Comment: @user3304303 One more thing change **var other= 5;** in your if/else block to just other=5. do the same for something.

Comment: That did it!  (along with your first suggestion).  Weird, so I guess something was weird with the scope and/or declaration of variables, which I obviously need to learn more about.  Anyway, thanks a lot!